# Создание объекта в методе

Tags: java

В классе User добавить метод setContacts с параметрами:
String email, String phoneNumber.
В этом методе должен создаватся объект класса Contacts,
и присваиватся в поле contacts класса User.
Я создаю объект в методе но он ругает и не знаю что делать подскажите плз.

public class User {

```
String name;
int age;
int gender;
Contacts contacts;

public User(String name, int age, int gender) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.gender = gender;
}

public User(String name, int age, int gender, Contacts contacts) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.contacts = contacts;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public int getGender() {
    return gender;
}

public void setGender(int gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}

public Contacts getContacts() {
    return contacts;
}

public void setContacts(Contacts contacts) {
    this.contacts = contacts;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "User{" + "name=" + name + ", age=" + age + ", gender=" + gender + ", contacts=" + contacts + '}';
}

private static class GenderFlags {

    final int NOT_SPECIFIED = 0;
    final int MALE = 1;
    final int FEMALE = 2;

}

class Contacts {

    String email;
    String phoneNumber;

    public Contacts(String email, String phoneNumber) {
        this.email = email;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Contacts{" + "email=" + email + ", phoneNumber=" + phoneNumber + '}';
    }

}

public void setContacts(String email, String phoneNumber){
  Contacts cs = new Contacts();
}
```

}

Comment: Ошибку в студию

Comment: `NullPointerException`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ты забыл присвоить локальную переменную в поле класса

```
public void setContacts(String email, String phoneNumber){
  Contacts cs = new Contacts(email, phoneNumber);
  setContacts(cs);
}
```

тут я воспользовался уже реализованным методом - может быть, ты захочешь еще что-то там сделать

Comment: Спасибо большое !

Answer (score 1):

Уберете class qew с main методом и восстановите модификаторы доступа к классам, а так все работает, метод setContacts с параметрами в User , который принимает 2 значения и создает новый объект, который присваивается полю. Если я ,конечно, правильно понял реализацию, так как в вашем выложенном коде был  не корректно расположены символ }.

```js
class qew{
public static void main(String[] args){
User u = new User("Name",92,1);
u.setContacts("asdasdad@yandex.ru","99938492");
Contacts c = u.getContacts(); 
System.out.println(c.getEmail()  + " -    Email   "  + c.getPhoneNumber() + "  Phone Contacts ");
}
}


class User {
String name;
int age;
int gender;
Contacts contacts;

public User(String name, int age, int gender) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.gender = gender;
}

public User(String name, int age, int gender, Contacts contacts) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.contacts = contacts;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public int getGender() {
    return gender;
}

public void setGender(int gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}

public Contacts getContacts() {
    return contacts;
}

public void setContacts(Contacts contacts) {
    this.contacts = contacts;
}
// setContacts !!!
public void setContacts(String email, String phoneNumber){
   this.contacts = new Contacts(email,phoneNumber);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "User{" + "name=" + name + ", age=" + age + ", gender=" + gender + ", contacts=" + contacts + '}';
}
}
class GenderFlags {

    final int NOT_SPECIFIED = 0;
    final int MALE = 1;
    final int FEMALE = 2;

}

class Contacts {

    String email;
    String phoneNumber;

    public Contacts(String email, String phoneNumber) {
        this.email = email;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Contacts{" + "email=" + email + ", phoneNumber=" + phoneNumber + '}';
    }
}
```